# Is Cape of the Mountebank's power really supposed to be a reaction?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

> Cape of the Mountebank Level 5+ Uncommon
>
> Power (Teleportation) Daily (Immediate Reaction)
>
> Use this power when you are hit by an attack. Teleport 5 squares and
>   gain combat advantage against the attacker until the end of your next
>   turn.

Do you think "reaction" is intended, so you take damage from hit, and then teleport, or is it "a case of mistaken interrupt", like with Parrying Weapon's ability? (here - [What is the timing of Parrying Weapon's ability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47114/what-is-the-timing-of-parrying-weapons-ability/47131#47131) )

So, how should I rule, damage or no damage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's probably intended. The power works fine - it's like [the pixie's teleport trick](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22679/1204). It's a reaction, and you take the entire attack before absconding to safety. Even if you can't evade the attack, it's still very useful in the hands of a ranged character: a free escape to safety from someone who closed in on you, and a temporary bonus to attacking them.

It's reasonable to suspect there's a mistake when a power is totally broken, but when it works fine and just surprises you with an uncommon effect, just take it as an unusual (but deliberate) feature.

Comment: There are also *tons* of multi-attacking monsters in 4e. This is a great power when dealing with those.

Answer (score -2):

The wording is there, even ignoring what sort of action there is.

> When **you are hit by the attack**

So yes, you are hit by the attack.

Comment: The same language is used by immediate _interrupt_ teleports, though. Consider the Sorcerer's *Swift Escape* (PHB2 142), which has a trigger of "You are hit by an area or close attack" and lets you teleport away a few squares. The idea is to teleport outside the range of the attack after the attack roll succeeds, leaving it unable to _actually_ hit you so you're unharmed by it.